# Way to add multiple documents to Solr V5 from Mysql results in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, perl, solr

I just followed the example [on this page](http://php.net/manual/ro/solrclient.adddocuments.php) as to how to add multiple documents from a database using Perl Solr extension.

Example Code:

```
$users = $dbh->prepare($sql);

$users->execute();

$result = $users->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($result as $k=>$r){
  $docs_array[$k] = new SolrInputDocument();

  $docs_array[$k]->addField('model_id', $r['model_id']);

  $docs_array[$k]->addField('name', $r['name']);
}

$updateResponse = $client->addDocument($docs_array);
```

It isn't working and giving this error:

```
Argument 1 passed to SolrClient::addDocument() must be an instance of SolrInputDocument, array given
```

So I guess the only way to make that work is adding documents one by one in each loop, like this:

```
foreach($result as $k=>$r){

  $doc = new SolrInputDocument();

  $doc->addField('model_id', $r['model_id']);

  $doc->addField('name', $r['name']);

  $updateResponse = $client->addDocument($doc);

}
```

Since there isn't enough document on this extension, I'd like to make sure if it is an appropriate way of doing that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're linking to the documentation for `addDocument->s<-` while calling `addDocument` (without the plural s at the end).

Use the correct method (`addDocuments`) and the documentation will be correct.